# From Array list encrypt every value inside array? Java

Tags: java, arrays, spring, encryption

**Is it possible to encrypt at every object value inside  the array? My encryptor accepts only strings and not array , i have been stuck for 4 days any help will be great!**

*i want to encrypt from [a,b,c,d,e] to --> [@#%,@#%,@#%,!@$!$,@#$@#%]*

**This is my encryption code!**

```
    public class Aes {
        private static final String SECRET_KEY = "my_super_secret_key_ho_ho_ho";
        private static final String SALT = "sfasf";
        public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt) {
            try {
                byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
                IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    
                SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
                KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.toCharArray(), SALT.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
                SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
                SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
    
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
                return Base64.getEncoder()
                        .encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
```

**And this is my reader code txt file to Array list:**

```
    public ArrayList reader() throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Give me the Data file here : ");
            String path = "";
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            path = sc.nextLine();
            if (path.contains(".txt")) {
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String str;
                String[] wordsArray;
                while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    wordsArray = str.split(" ");
                    for (String each : wordsArray) {
                        if (!"".equals(each)) {
                            words.add(each);
                        }
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(words);
                br.close();
                return words;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong type,try again");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"i have been stuck for 4 days"* **--** within this 4 days you never came up with the idea to do some kind of *looping* over the array? I downvoted because [No attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tag, removed `python`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Stream#map`.

```java
List<String> list = List.of("a", "b", "c");
List<String> result = list.stream().map(Aes::encrypt).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you very much this help me a lot! , can you please explain me what is Aes::encrypt ? thank you again very much ,  you are awesome!

Comment: @JuniorDeveloper It's a method reference to the static `encrypt` method in your `Aes` class.

Comment: @JuniorDeveloper See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: By the way, in Java 16+ we can shorten `.collect(Collectors.toList())` to this: `.toList()`.